# Is there a way to parse out the computer name

Tags: javascript

I have some code but I just found out it works on like 90% of the computers. Here is the distinguishedName:
*CN=2016-10-05T12:19:16-05:00{393DA5A5-4EEF-4394-90F7-CBD0D2F20CC9},CN=**Computer01-T2**,OU=Product,OU=Workstations,OU=KDUYA,DC=time,DC=local*

What I am trying to do is parse out just the ComputerName. 3 of the 27 OU we have use 3 letter Names instead of the 5 which all the other sites use.  Ive been banging my head against the wall and reaching out for some help and or guidance. Watching some videos on regex understand the basics but still working on more complicated things like this.

Here is what I have. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
let str = "CN=2016-10-05T12:19:16-05:00{393DA5A5-4EEF-4394-90F7-CBD0D2F20CC9},CN=Computer01-T2,OU=Product,OU=Workstations,OU=KDUYA,DC=time,DC=local";
str = str.substring(70, str.length -53);
console.log(str);+
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are your requirements exactly? What are some names it works on, some it doesn't work on, and why?

Comment: you can use regex `str.match(",CN=(.*?),")[1]`, if the order is fixed, you can split the string by `,` and parse each element, you can do what you already do, but determine the end by the next `,` many ways

Comment: Thanks.. Im trying here.  so with  `str.match(",CN=(.*?),")[1]` we are saying look for (CN= the ( group .* would be everything. I dont understand the rest after that.  what does ? mean? just trying to follow along

Some of the OU we have do not follow a standard naming convention.  Most are 5 letters and but some have 3.

Comment: I really appreciate the help.  Im watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa-TUpSx1JA but looking for more info.  Like one for dummies. I understand most of this and testing it out.  I like the problem solving aspect about it. Again many thanks and if you can point me into the right directions maybe i can be helping others here too

Comment: This looks like an x500 DN. In that case please do yourself a favor and just find a rfc2253 library. There are  escape sequences, arbitrary ordering and other things that very hard to get right in regex alone. The question mark at the end of .* means match lazy. it will match the shortest possible string, for .* that would mean zero to unlimited chars which reduces down to matching and returning an empty string, if there is no following comma.

Comment: Yes  but had to look up what X500DN is.I will dig into rfc2253 library.  Thanks Hans

Comment: You can read about how the regex pattern I created works here: https://regex101.com/r/wM8ejj/1 I will edit my answer and add comments as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regular expression:

```
let str = "CN=2016-10-05T12:19:16-05:00{393DA5A5-4EEF-4394-90F7-CBD0D2F20CC9},CN=Computer01-T2,OU=Product,OU=Workstations,OU=KDUYA,DC=time,DC=local";
let myRegexp = /^[^,]+,CN=([^,]+)/;
let match = myRegexp.exec(str);

console.log(match[1]); // Computer01-T2
```

The /`^`[^,]+,CN=([^,]+)/ portion means start looking for a match starting at the beginning of the string

"`start here|`CN=2016-10-05T12:19:16-05:00{393DA5A5-4EEF-4394-90F7-CBD0D2F20CC9},CN=Computer01-T2,OU=Product,OU=Workstations,OU=KDUYA,DC=time,DC=local"

The /^`[^,]`+,CN=([^,]+)/ portion means to match any character except for a comma

"`C`N=2016-10-05T12:19:16-05:00{393DA5A5-4EEF-4394-90F7-CBD0D2F20CC9},CN=Computer01-T2,OU=Product,OU=Workstations,OU=KDUYA,DC=time,DC=local"

The /^[^,]`+`,CN=([^,]+)/ portion means to match as many, non-comma in this case, characters in a row as possible.

"`CN=2016-10-05T12:19:16-05:00{393DA5A5-4EEF-4394-90F7-CBD0D2F20CC9}`,CN=Computer01-T2,OU=Product,OU=Workstations,OU=KDUYA,DC=time,DC=local"

The /^[^,]+`,CN=`([^,]+)/ portion means to exactly match a string: ,CN=

"`CN=2016-10-05T12:19:16-05:00{393DA5A5-4EEF-4394-90F7-CBD0D2F20CC9},CN=`Computer01-T2,OU=Product,OU=Workstations,OU=KDUYA,DC=time,DC=local"

The /^[^,]+,CN=`(`[^,]+`)`/ The parens means to store the matching part of the string so that we can get it's value, aka a "match group", and will contain the computer name portion of the string in this case.

The /^[^,]+,CN=(`[^,]+`)/ portion means to match as many non-comma characters in a row as possible.

"`CN=2016-10-05T12:19:16-05:00{393DA5A5-4EEF-4394-90F7-CBD0D2F20CC9},CN=Computer01-T2`,OU=Product,OU=Workstations,OU=KDUYA,DC=time,DC=local"

As you can see from the comments on your post that there are many different ways you can structure a regular expression.  I prefer to anchor my matches to the start of the strings I am parsing, aka the /`^[^,]+`,CN=([^,]+)/ part.

The regex101 website is a great place to experiment with and learn about regular expressions.

This link pre-populates that site with your example string and the regular expression I used in this answer:  https://regex101.com/r/wM8ejj/1/

Comment: or `/,CN=(.*?),/`

Comment: Thank you so much. If you have time could you just give me a brief explanation. So i can follow it. I really trying to learn more here.  TY again sir

Comment: TY Drew so much.  i have to digest this but working on it

Answer (score 0):

with the string that you have given you can use this snippet

```
let str = "CN=2016-10-05T12:19:16-05:00{393DA5A5-4EEF-4394-90F7-CBD0D2F20CC9},CN=Computer01-T2,OU=Product,OU=Workstations,OU=KDUYA,DC=time,DC=local";

let cName = str.split(',').find(e => e.indexOf('Computer') != -1).split('=')[1];

console.log(cName);
```

This assumes all your computer names will have the keyword *Computer* in there. You can modify the snippet per your needs.

Comment: This falsely assumes that all computer names have "computer" in their names.

Comment: That's why the disclaimer. :)

Comment: ty.  It still show me different ways to look at things.